# Why doesn't the second image go under the first when I resize the web page?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am nesting what I believe is an [img col-xs-6] plus [img col-xs-6] under a [jumbotron col-xs-12].

Why doesn't the second image go under the first when I resize the web page?

```
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row col-xs-12 jumbotron">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://cdn8.openculture.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Tolkien-publisher-3.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/0/2848/425335-tolkien_photo_c.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using `xs-` classes which means 2 columns on XS size window (mobile devices). You can change `col-xs-6` to for example `col-md-6` and you will have two columns on MD screens and 1 column on SM (tablet) and XS (mobile) screens.

Also you shouldn't have `row` after `row` immediately.

```
<div class="jumbotron>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://cdn8.openculture.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Tolkien-publisher-3.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/0/2848/425335-tolkien_photo_c.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### **[Learn more (Bootstrap grid system)](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)**

### **[Learn more (Jumbotron)](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron)**

Comment: Although col-md-6 fixes it, I don't understand why col-xs-6 doesn't work. I have resulted in col-xs-6 because I want to add an offset only when it reaches below md width.

Comment: @Achilles - `col-xs-6` = "I want this to be 6 columns wide when the screen is extra-small sized or bigger (i.e. always)". `col-md-6` = "I want this to be 6 columns at medium size or bigger (i.e. not including small or extra-small)".

Comment: `col-xs-6` means that the width of this container will be always 50% regardless of the screen size. That's why it doesn't work how you want.

Comment: Nice, now I get it. Another question; when I set my images to col-sm-6 and I resize my page to extra-small, how do I add col-xs-offset-1 just for extra-small sizes/devices? I want my elements to be centered.

Comment: You can add `col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1` - it means 10 culumns wide and 1 column offset from the left (effect: 1 - 10 - 1).

Comment: Is there a way to work like that for extra-small and using another setup for small or bigger? `col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-12` in one line keeps the offset for small devices...

Comment: Yes, if you use offset class for XS screen you have to define offset for SM class. In your case it can be: `col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0`